# How do I pass the post ID in this code?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to pass the post ID in the code below. How can I add it in there? I think I need to add `$post->ID` somewhere.

```
$wp_query->query( 'post_type=movies&p=' . $_GET['pid']);
```

Comment: From where are you getting that post ID value? post more code please!

Answer (score 0):

You answered you question.

`I am trying to pass the post ID in the code below.`

If it's post.
`$_GET['pid']` should be `$_POST['pid']`

Comment: I don't think they meant "POST" as in HTTP verb, but "post" as in wordpress blog post.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
$wp_query->query( 'post_type=movies&p=' . $post->ID);
```

Will do it?

Comment: Unfortunately, this pulls up no posts at all.

Comment: OK, first up use `echo '$post->ID = '.$post->ID` before this line to ensure that there is a value in that variable. If there is, check whether there is a post with that ID and of the type "movies", as that is the rest of your query. If there isn't one, then the query is performing as expected. Otherwise, to give an accurate answer, we'll need more info, like a live URL and the expected output.